# How to control ram usage for a specific user application with cgroups and systemd?

Tags: systemd, cgroups

I am kind of pissed off by the browsers memory use. I would like to limit the total memory used by Chrome, opera, firefox etc. to 800MB for example.

It looks like a job for cgroups.

I've read about `cgexec` and it would do what I want...

However, I would also like to "prepare" a group called "internet", using a similar method as described here :
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/cgroups#Persistent_group_configuration

And since it's mentioned :

> Note: when using Systemd >= 205 to manage cgroups, you can ignore this file entirely.

I'm a bit scared. (and Google finds results relevent for the situation before systemd, but it's a blur for the current situation)

Since Systemd looks like it's becoming the new standard, how to do it with a long term support ?

(...And am I missing/messing something here, because it's quite unclear to me to be honest)

Answer (score 0):

I generally think it is a bad idea since Chrome will probably crash when it will not able to allocate any more memory.
Alternatively, it will swap its data to the disk which is even worse.
Chrome's high memory consumption is what makes it fast.

If you insist on creating a cgroup for your browsers, I suggest creating a script that first creates the cgroups if it does not exist, then runs the application given in the script's parameters.